# how to check if limit is approaching in my trigger

Tags: apex, soql

I want to check if I'm nearing limits in my trigger and display a message to the user if they hit the limit.

I have the following method that I am calling from my trigger that retrieves a large number of records from another object that I need to iterate over.  The records I'm returning are not on the object that my trigger fires.  So, I want to be able to display a message to the user if the records returned are surpassing the limit?  How do I bubble up the error to the object that the trigger fires on?

```
private List<MyCustomObject__c> getAllRecords() {
    List<MyCustomObject__c> results = new List<MyCustomObject__c>();
    for(List<MyCustomObject__c> items : [select Id, Field1__c, Field2__c, Field3__c, Color__c, Account__r.Name, Account__c from MyCustomObject__c where Status__c = 'Open']) {
        results.addAll(items);
    }
    return results;
}
```

So, my query can only retrieve 50,000 records, correct?  I want to display a message to the user if the query is going to return more than 50,000  records.

so, I am I correct that I can use the following:

```
private List<MyCustomObject__c> getAllRecords() {
    List<MyCustomObject__c> results = new List<MyCustomObject__c>();
    for(List<MyCustomObject__c> items : [select Id, Field1__c, Field2__c, Field3__c, Color__c, Account__r.Name, Account__c from MyCustomObject__c where Status__c = 'Open']) {
        if(Limits.getQueryRows() > Limits.getLimitQueryRows()) {
             //how do I bubble up the error message to the user?    
        }
        else {
             results.addAll(items);
        }
    return results;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

items.addError('Your Error Message');

Comment: Thanks for replying to my post, but that doesn't work.  `items` is a list of SOjbects, but not the object that my trigger fires on.  So, there is no `addError` method for a list.

Comment: @Dman100 can you post your full trigger

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of solutions here:

Option 1. If the `getAllRecords` has access to Trigger.new, you need to correlate the invocation of the `getAllRecords` to one of the *ith* elements in Trigger.new.  This will usually require keeping a correlation map and then you can use addError on the triggered record of the batch that corresponds to the limits issue

Option 2. If #1 is too hard or not applicable, simply mark all records in the triggered batch with addError and then the whole batch fails

Option 3. Throw a custom exception; if your code is invoked by a controller, then the controller should be try-catching around any DML call - then doing a rollback and issuing an apexPages.message; if code is invoked by standard Force.com page, SFDC will catch your exception and display

Answer (score 0):

Remember that there is a heap limit too so returning all the queried rows is usually a bad idea as even a few hundred bytes per row will take you over the 6M governor limit if you get close to 50,000 records.

As governor limit exceptions can't be caught, the best you can do is use the limit term of SOQL and report when the number of rows returned is equal to that limit:

```
List<MyCustomObject__c> items : [
        select Id, Field1__c, Field2__c, Field3__c, Color__c, Account__r.Name, Account__c
        from MyCustomObject__c
        where Status__c = 'Open'
        limit 40000
        ];
if (items.size() == 40000) {
    throw new MyException('At least 40,000 rows returned (could be a lot more)');
}
```

The 40,000 choice here is to leave 10,000 spare for other queries done in the same transaction.